# Word- VBA- How To Delete Selected Row in A Table and Protect First Two Rows?

Tags: vba, ms-word, rowdeleting

The following code successfully deletes the selection in a table.

```
If Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
    Selection.Rows.Delete
End If
```

Furthermore, the following code successfully prevents the first two table rows from deletion but deletes from the bottom row up not based on selection.

```
Dim index As Long
    For index = ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows.Count To 3 Step -1
        ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows(index).Delete
    Exit For
    Next index
```

Is there a way to combine the two so I can delete any selected row but prevent the first two rows from deletion?

Comment: You can't "protect the parent row" (whatever you think a "parent" row is). Content controls are different objects than tables and have different properties and methods.

Comment: @JohnKorchok - he means how can the code be adapted to delete a selected table row, but not allow the first row to be deleted.

Comment: Thanks, after I read his previous post, I got that idea. You still can't protect a row from deletion in the same way you can with a content control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be helpful if you stated *clearly* what you're trying to achieve. Try something along the lines of:

```
Sub Demo()
With Selection
  If .Information(wdWithInTable) = False Then Exit Sub
  If .Cells(.Cells.Count).RowIndex > 2 Then
    If .Cells(1).RowIndex < 3 Then
      .Start = .Tables(1).Rows(3).Range.Start
    End If
    .Rows.Delete
  End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you sir. My apologies. I edited my question to provide more clarity. I actually need to protect the first two rows. Changing your code ```Rows(2)``` to ```Rows(3)``` and  ```=1``` to ```>=1``` prevents the first two rows from deletion so long as I select row 1 or 2.  However, for example, if there is a table with 5 rows and I select row 4, it will delete rows 3-4.  If I select row 5, it will delete rows 3-5 and so on.  Goal would be to select row 4 and delete only row 4.  Same with row 5.  Almost there.

Comment: Yet another variation! You really like to make it difficult for anyone to help you solve *your* problem... See revised code.

Comment: Thank you sir.  Sorry for the confusion!